# Compiling Dipha on Ubuntu with CMAKE

Tags: cmake

I have been trying to compile an application called Dipha. The advice from their instructions is to build the application with the CCMAKE command, you can press the letter **c** to configure the build. Then from the **g** Key to generate the build files. However, the **g** option isn't available so I can't build the app.

Am I missing some configuration? [image: Image to show the missing g option]

https://github.com/DIPHA/dipha

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get around this by just using cmake command.

- Created a new directory to build the application, one level up outside of the main Dipha repo
- cd into build directory
- ran `cmake ../dipha` to generate build files
- then make to compile everything.
- Moved binaries into bin